# Problema com Linq em Lambda: LINQ to Entities does not recognize... get_Item(Int32). Como resolver?

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda, entity-framework-6

Ao tentar executar o laço `for` (momento em que a query é executa) está dando erro em minha expressão lambda:

```cs
var funcionarios = repository.Funcionarios
    .Include(x => x.Cargo)
    .Include(x => x.Bairro)
    .Include(x => x.Bairro.Cidade)
    .Include(x => x.Historicos)
    .Where(x => x.Historicos
        .Count(hist => hist.TipoHistoricoId == parametros.HistoricoManutencaoCargoId &&
            hist.DataRegistro.Year == AnoBase) > 0)
    .Where(x => x.Bairro != null && x.Bairro.Cidade != null)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Bairro.Cidade.Id)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.Historicos[0].DataRegistro);

foreach (var func in funcionarios)
{
...
}
```

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Domain.FuncionarioHistorico get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

`Domain.FuncionarioHistorico` refere-se à propriedade `Historicos` do Funcionário que está sendo carregada por: `.Include(x => x.Historicos)`.

Aparentemente minha expressão para para o ***Join / Include*** não está correta, ou preciso armazenar em variável algum dos valores utilizados nela para então passar para a expressão.

O `parametros` é uma variável local que armazena alguns parâmetros do sistema, inclusive o Tipo de Histórico que é utilizado para manutenção de cargos. `HistoricoManutencaoCargoId` é a propriedade que acessa o `Id` desse tipo.

Havendo necessidade do modelo eu adiciono um pequeno exemplo pois o atual é grande.

**Como resolver isso?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `Include` espera um objeto **complexo** relacionado do seu *Model*: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696785(v=vs.113).aspx

Portanto, o que causa o problema não é o `Include`, e sim o `Count`, que dentro de um `Where` não pode ser traduzido imediatamente. Por isso o erro.

Em todo caso, esse jeito que está escrito está esquisito. Você pode simplificar para:

```
var funcionarios = repository.Funcionarios
    .Include(x => x.Cargo)
    .Include(x => x.Bairro)
    .Include(x => x.Bairro.Cidade)
    .Include(x => x.Historicos)
    .Where(x => x.Bairro != null && x.Bairro.Cidade != null)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Bairro.Cidade.Id)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.Historicos[0].DataRegistro);

funcionarios = funcionarios.SelectMany(f => f.Historicos)
    .Where(hist => hist.TipoHistoricoId == parametros.HistoricoManutencaoCargoId &&
            hist.DataRegistro.Year == AnoBase)
    .Select(hist => hist.Funcionario)
    .ToList();
```