# Como fazer uma ordenação com Lambda por uma propriedade do tipo Lista?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda, order

Acredito que isso já tenha sido perguntado antes. Pesquisei mas não encotrei.

Estou tendo problema nessa consulta, especificamente no comando `ThenBy` que tenta ordernar a sub-lista de objetos. Sei que é nele porque ao comentá-lo, o erro não ocorre:

```cs
var menus = _context.MenuRaiz
    .Include(x => x.Menus)
    .Include(x => x.Menus.Select(m => m.GruposAcesso))
    .Where(x => x.Menus.Any(m => m.GruposAcesso.Any(g => g.Id == permissoes.GrupoAcessoId)))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Ordem)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Menus[0].Ordem) // <-- esse é o culpado! pega ele..
    .ToList();
```

Costumo usar **[dessa forma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29446/problema-com-linq-em-lambda-linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-get-itemint)**, mas não sei porque não está dando.

**Mensagem de erro**:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'CRM.Domain.Menu get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Exemplo das classes:

**MenuRaiz**:

```cs
public class MenuRaiz 
{
    public MenuRaiz() {
        Menus = new List<Menu>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Ordem { get; set; }        

    [InverseProperty("MenuRaiz")]
    public virtual List<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
}
```

**Menu**:

```cs
public class Menu
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Ordem { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MenuRaiz")]
    public int MenuRaizId { get; set; }
    public virtual MenuRaiz MenuRaiz { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Menu")]
    public virtual List<GruposAcesso> GruposAcesso { get; set; }
}
```

Qual a forma correta de fazer essa ordenação?

Comment: O tradutor de expressões do LINQ to Entities não pode ler variáveis "complexas" como Arrays, por isso o erro.

Answer (score 5):

Diretamente de ***[Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11041055)***:

```
.OrderBy(e => e.Schedules.Min(s => s.StartDateTime))
```

Logo, para o meu caso:

```
.ThenBy(x => x.Menus.Min(m => m.Ordem))
```